# No notification when employer sends reply on Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, email-notification

I received an auto email when an employer contacted me on careers.stackoverflow.com. I responded and then they responded back. I did not receive an email when they responded back. Is this a setting I can change? If so where is it?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry about that Andy.  We had a bad policy in place that only sent an e-mail for the first message in a chain.  The new policy is that every message gets an e-mail and it's in place now.

Comment: Great news. Thanks for fixing this!